# Trying to create a runnable jar / app out of my Java Project in Eclipse (Mac)

Tags: eclipse, macos, jar, runnable

So I know that I can make a .jar file by exporting my project with eclipse... but that doesn't work. I've tried it.

My project contains 10 different classes, and a folder that contains images and fonts used in the app. I thought I should just be able to make a jar file and run it. Keeps telling me "Could not create java virtual machine" when I run it through terminal.

I just need to be able to run it without using an IDE

Comment: Are you passing in any parameters, such as Xmx?  If so, double-check that they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fat Jar eclipse plugin for exporting Java projects to runnable jar.

More info [see here](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).